# Rails associations many to many through join table

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have the following models: `Organisation`, `Valuation` and `Capability`.

The `Organisation` model used to have a country field, but it came to my attention it can have multiple locations.

To solve this I could create a `Location` model and add a `has_many` relation between `Organisation` and `Location`, equally however a location can belong to more than one organisation. For example, Organisation X might have a location in UK, DE and US and organisation Y might have a location in UK and DE.

The bigger problem lies with `Valuation` which describes valuations of a  organisation ***at a specific location*** for a specific capability. So where the valuation at organisation X in location Y might be 10, it could be 8 for organisation X at location Z.

Right now `Valuation` has `belongs_to` assocations to both `Organisation` and `Capability`:

```
class Valuation < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :organisation
  belongs_to :capability
end
```

To account for the location, I would need to add another association, but I am looking for some hints as to which one.

The question then is, how to set up my assocations so I can ask questions like:

"*what is the average valuation of organisation x with capability y over all locations*"

or

"*what is the valuation of organsiation x for capability y at location z*"

***EDIT***

Ended up going with the `many-to-many` approach, ended up with the models:

```
class Organisation < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :memberships
  has_many :locations, through: :memberships
end

class Location < ApplicationRecord    
  has_many :memberships
  has_many :organisations, through: :memberships
end

class Membership < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :organisation
  belongs_to :location
end
```

Question now is to link this to `Valuation`

Comment: Can help with the whole answer now, but how about making a valuation with composite primary key? 

Meaning, one valuation can only exists having an Organization and a Location?

And, Organization - Location relationship should be many to many

Comment: Also, whats the relation of Capability with the other entities?

Comment: Capability has no relationships, short of a Valution `belongs_to` a Capability

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The relationship between `Organization` and `Location` is actually many-to-many. What you need is a joined table `OrganizationsLocation`, whose table is `organizations_locations` with schema `organization_id` and `location_id`.

And, the valuation should actually belong to an `OrganizationsLocation` record.

```
class OrganizationsLocation < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :organization
  belongs_to :location

  has_many :valuations
end
```

Organization could have many valuations through above model.

```
class Organization < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :organizations_locations
  has_many :valuations, through: :organizations_locations
end
```

For your first question "what is the average valuation of organization x with capability y over all locations", you could get all the valuations with below code and calculate the average:

```
x.valuations.where(capability_id: y.id)
```

For your second question: "what is the valuation of organization x for capability y at location z":

```
OrganizationsLocation.find_by(organization_id: x.id, location_id: z.id).valuations.find_by(capability_id: y.id)
```

UPDATE:

Since you already have a joined table `memberships`, which is the same with my suggested table `organizations_locations`, it could fit your needs.

You `Valuation` should `belongs_to` a `Membership` instead of `Organization`.

```
class Valuation < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :membership
  belongs_to :capability
end

x.valuations.where(capability_id: y.id)

Membership.find_by(organization_id: x.id, location_id: z.id).valuations.find_by(capability_id: y.id)
```

Comment: Thanks! I made an edit to my post, as there seems to be some associations missing in your proposal. Also chose a different name for the join table.